# How to install node-hid for electron

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm trying to get a simple electron application running that interacts with an HID device.
I am running into a lot of difficulty, I am able to install and run `node-hid`, just not within electron.

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "test-proj",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "main.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron .",
        "rebuild": "electron-rebuild --force",
        "postinstall": "electron-rebuild"
    },
    "author": "me",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "electron": "^9.2.0",
        "electron-rebuild": "^1.11.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "node-hid": "^1.3.0"
    }
}
```

My main.js has the standard electron demo boilerplate code plus some HID calls:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron');
var HID = require('node-hid');
var device = new HID.HID(5824, 1500);
// Standard electron app window stuff
```

When trying to run the app I immediately get an error on `new HID.HID()`:

```
Error: Module did not self-register: '\\?\C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\carriage_return_app\node_modules\node-hid\build\Release\HID.node'.
    at process.func [as dlopen] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140:31)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1034:18)
    at Object.func [as .node] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140:31)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:769:28)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at bindings (C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\carriage_return_app\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:112:48)
    at loadBinding (C:\Users\Nathan\Desktop\carriage_return_app\node_modules\node-hid\nodehid.js:25:42)
```

Looking around I have seen a few examples of how to install node-hid and use it in electron, but none have helped me.

I have followed the electron-rebuild instructions here: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules

I have also followed the instructions and copied the examples from here: https://github.com/node-hid/node-hid#electron-projects-using-node-hid

No luck. I get `module did not self-register` every time. node-hid is supposed to support electron and I don't see other people complaining.
Anyone come across this or have ideas to fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been solved, so I will mark this as answered. I think I would still like more information on WHY though.

The hint came from building the two example projects:

- https://github.com/todbot/electron-hid-toy
- https://github.com/todbot/electron-hid-test

Running the first item, `electron-hid-test` worked off the bat. Adding `electron-builder` as a dependency and adding `"postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"` as a script solved the issue in my project, I don't want `electron-builder` yet but at least it indicated that node-hid can work with electron given a specific setup.

The second item also worked, but not with:

1. `npm install`
2. `npm rebuild`
3. `npm start`

Instead it was specifically required to add the `run` command to the rebuild command:

1. `npm install`
2. `npm run rebuild`
3. `npm start`

After that, it works.
Any insights as to why this behaves differently?

Comment: The reason for the different behaviour is that in the first case you're using the rebuild script from npm, which is this one https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-rebuild, in the second case you're telling npm to use the script named "rebuild" amongs the ones you defined. Bottom line is those two commands run different scripts, and only the second one runs the script you defined. Hope this helps